# Rails make record readonly after update attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

My model has a attribute `void`. If `void` is true, I want the record to be readonly.
I tried:

```
def readonly?
  self.void
end
```

but this would disable me from saving the record because void is already true before I saved it. Saving a record with `void=true` would raise `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` exception. So I could never actually store `void=true` in the database.

**How can I make the record `readonly` after I have save `void=true`**

Comment: could you provide your validation?

Comment: @OlegSobchuk I only validate other fields and not void, so I don't think it would matter? (or am I wrong?). Saving the record after setting `void=true` would cause it to raise `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` error, which seems to be independent from rails validation.

Answer (score 1):

```
def readonly?
  persisted? && void
end
```

**EDIT**

it will working just for new records.

if you need use for persisted records you can do it in next way:

in your model:

```
attr_accessor :editable

def readonly?
  editable || !void ? false : true
end
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, I think this would only work if the object is a new_record?.

Comment: edited, check it out. And if you found my answer as useful please, mark it useful, thanks

Comment: am I suppose to do something with `editable`? I think it's `nil` as is.

Comment: exactly, but now in controller you can set it `true` if you want. For example: `params[:name_your_object].merge(edidable: true) if current_user.admin?`

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking if there's been changes to the `void` attribute ?

E.g.

```
def readonly?
  !void_just_changed? && void
end

def void_just_changed?
  void_was.blank? && void?
end
```

You can modify `void_just_changed?` to whatever suits you, e.g allow void to be set back to false.

Comment: So I need to add another field to keep track of the change? Was hoping that there is a cleaner way :(

Comment: No, it's not another field. `void_was` is a Rails generated method that returns you the value of `void` before a change. see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this without adding any variables, however, the resulting behavior is a bit different.

```
def readonly?
  begin
    prev = self.class.find(self.id)
    prev.void && self.void
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    false
  end
end
```

With this method, the record will correctly be marked readonly, but modifying its attributes is allowed, you will just not be able to save it. Conversely, if you manually return true from `readonly?` method, then a `ReadOnlyRecord` would be raise (which I think is preferable). **It would be great if anyone can explain why.**

Answer (score 0):

I have another variant:

```
  def readonly?
    !persisted? || void_changed? ? false : void
  end
```

Its means every time when you change void record is not readonly in other cases readlonly? depends from **void**